# (iOS) Success to get token, but cannot get the result from web API when the app opening the second time

Tags: azure-active-directory

I am using ADAL 2.4.1(for iOS). The app gets the token successfully after login the Azure AD and able to use the token for calling the web API and getting the data. However, I quitted/ killed the app and open the app again. The app still can get the token, but it cannot get the data from the web API. The server would return an HTML script to the app.

The app would log in the Azure AD to get the access token and store it in the app (using the keychain). I will use the stored access token to call the API.

A function to get the API:

```
ADAuthenticationContext *authContext = [ADAuthenticationContext authenticationContextWithAuthority:AUTHORITY_URL error:nil];
authContext.credentialsType = AD_CREDENTIALS_AUTO;
NSURL *redirectUri = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:REDIRECT_URI];

[authContext acquireTokenWithResource:"api_path"
                             clientId:CLIENT_ID
                          redirectUri:redirectUri
                       promptBehavior:AD_PROMPT_AUTO
                               userId:nil
                 extraQueryParameters: @""
                      completionBlock:^(ADAuthenticationResult *result)
 {
     if (result.status != AD_SUCCEEDED)
     {
         completionBlock(nil, nil, result.error);
     }
     else
     {
         completionBlock(result.tokenCacheItem.userInformation, result.tokenCacheItem.accessToken, nil);
     }
 }];
```

A function to get the data form WebAPI :

```
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:"API Path"];
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)postData.length];

    [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest new];
    [request setURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setTimeoutInterval: 15];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];       
    NSString* authValueToken = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@", "ADAL Token"];
    [request setValue:authValueToken forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:opsQueue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
     {
         NSString* resultString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
         NSLog(@"result : %@", resultString);
```

Start app at the first time, the app needs to login Azure AD or using another app "Microsoft Authenticator" to get the token. It is successful to get token and get the data from web API. Also, the app would store the token in the app (using keychain).

Start app at the second time, since I select AD_PROMPT_AUTO in the function "acquireTokenWithResource". The app would automatically check if the token(store in the keychain) is expired first. If not expired, it would be using this token to call the API. However, the server returns an HTML script to the app. This HTML script is same as a login page.

HTML script:

```
             Sign in to your account

<noscript>
    <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; URL=https://login.microsoftonline.com/jsdisabled" />
</noscript>


    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://secure.aadcdn.microsoftonline-p.com/ests/2.1.8383.13/content/images/favicon_a_eupayfgghqiai7k9sol6lg2.ico" />

<meta name="robots" content="none" />
https://login.live.com/logout.srf?iframed_by=https%3a%2f%2flogin.microsoftonline.com","urlUxPreviewOptOut":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/uxpreview/optout","showCantAccessAccountLink":true,"fShowAsyncTileLoad":true,"urlFeatureAnnouncementBlogPost":"https://aka.ms/AA1edlw","fCollapseExcessLinks":true,"fShowLoginV2PreviewLink":true,"fEnableShowResendCode":true,"iShowResendCodeDelay":90000,"sSMSCtryPhoneData":"AF~Afghanistan~93!!!AX~Ã…land.....
```

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that the API you are trying to access does not identify the request as an authenticated request, and is redirecting the client to sign in with Azure AD. This behavior is somewhat strange, but could be explained if the API is also an endpoint which can be visited in a browser.

It is possible that your client (the mobile app) is not sending the access token correctly in the request. In you code, you have the following line:

```
NSString* authValueToken = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@", "ADAL Token"];
```

If that is actually what you have in your app's code, then you would need to update this to actually use the access token (obtained from ADAL) in the `Authorization` header, not the string "ADAL Token".